# Error Installing, apk installed failed install_parse_failed_manifest_malformed

Tags: android, android-manifest

i know, its a very common question but i tried enough and ended up with this error for the application that i downloaded and tried to install.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.helloandroid.android.newsdroid">
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  <activity class=".FeedsList" android:label="@string/app_name">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:value="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:value="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity class=".URLEditor" android:label="@string/url_editor" />
    <activity class=".ArticlesList" android:label="@string/articles_list" />
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Comment: That is not valid XML, as you are missing the `</manifest>` tag. That should not even compile.

Comment: sorry, i missed that while pasting it

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below Format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.abc.ABC"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```